# Replace array values by another one in a string

Tags: php, arrays

i try to replace array values by another one in a string, i can't find any PHP function could do this.

this is my code :

```
array_replace(array('id','quote_id'), array('new field 1','new field 2'), $string)
```

this is my string

```
SELECT id,quote_id,total FROM quotes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ar = array('id','quote_id');
$replace = array('new field 1','new field 2');

$str = 'SELECT id, quote_id,total FROM quotes';

for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\b$ar[$i]\b/u", $replace[$i], $str);
}

echo $str;
```